# Problem calculating in SELECT based on 2 subqueries on same table

Tags: sql, select, subquery, calculation

I have a table containing meter readings logged on monthly basis including information on sunshine hours and heating degree days.
Using this table I try to calculate efficiency in our solarpanels as kwh produced per sunhour - on yearly basis. Goal is to identify possible decrease in production over time (age of solarpanels).

I can use meter readings to calculate yearly consumption (by subtracting last year end reading form this year end reading)  - and I can sum up sunhours (monthly reading per year) - but my (selflearned) skills does enable me to get the combined calculation to work.

Result should be result listing 'Season, efficiency' to use in a graphing tool.

**First attempt:**

```
SELECT
    season,
    solarpanel - LAG(solarpanel, 1, 17449) OVER( ORDER BY season) AS kwh
FROM 
    kv28c_meterreadings_readings 
WHERE 
    reading = 12

UNION 

SELECT 
    season, SUM(sun_hrs) AS hours
FROM 
    kv28c_meterreadings_readings
GROUP BY 
    season
ORDER BY 
    season
```

This returns a list:

```
season     kwh
-----------------
2018/19    1891.0
2018/19    1925.0
2019/20    1802.2
2019/20    1770.0
```

Now I need to divide the second row by the first row.

**Latest attempt:**

```
SELECT
    k.season,
    (k.solarpanel - LAG(k.solarpanel, 1, 17449) OVER( ORDER BY k.season)) / SUM(h.sun_hrs) AS k.efficiency
FROM 
    kv28c_meterreadings_readings k 
WHERE 
    k.reading = 12
JOIN 
    kv28c_meterreadings_readings h ON k.season = h.season 
ORDER BY 
    k.season
```

which fails on syntax at `WHERE`.

What to do?

Comment: It's `SELECT ... FROM .... JOIN ... JOIN ... JOIN ... WHERE .... ORDER BY`  - **all** JOINs **must come before** the `WHERE` clause - you cannot mix JOIN and WHERE at will

Comment: it would be better to use two CTE and then divide them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get your numbers, you can use two cte and join the results

```
WITH CTE_Reading as(
SELECT
    season,
    solarpanel - LAG(solarpanel, 1, 17449) OVER( ORDER BY season) AS kwh
FROM 
    kv28c_meterreadings_readings 
WHERE 
    reading = 12),
CTE_group as(
SELECT 
    season, SUM(sun_hrs) AS hours
FROM 
    kv28c_meterreadings_readings
GROUP BY 
    season)
SELECT c1.season, kwh/hours
FROM CTE_Reading c1 JOIN CTE_group c2 ON c1.season = c2.season
ORDER BY 
    c1.season
```

the query without CTE

```
SELECT c1.season, kwh/hours
FROM (
SELECT
    season,
    solarpanel - LAG(solarpanel, 1, 17449) OVER( ORDER BY season) AS kwh
FROM 
    kv28c_meterreadings_readings 
WHERE 
    reading = 12)   c1 JOIN (
SELECT 
    season, SUM(sun_hrs) AS hours
FROM 
    kv28c_meterreadings_readings
GROUP BY 
    season) c2 ON c1.season = c2.season
ORDER BY 
    c1.season
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, and sorry for delay in getting back.

Your solution works fine running it in phpMyAdmin :-)

Unfortunately it seems my graphing tool (Plotalot) does not allow WITH: "error: Plot 1 Queries must begin with select"

I'll try and contact developers. Is there a way using only SELECT?

BR Frank

Comment: i added the same query with CTE, it is quite simple to convert when you look at it, try the new one

Comment: also provide a dbfiddle with data, as you need for that query to work, to have for every season a row with reading 12

Comment: Brilliant :-) - thx a lot, working great!

Just for general info: Plotalot actually has an option to inactivate the "SELECT" requirement. Trying this I got other problems even though the "WITH" solution works in direct query.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your table structure, it's hard to know what the best answer would be but I've come up with two possibilities.

No joins - Everything is coming from the same table. Pull it all at the same time.

```
 SELECT season
      , solarpanel - LAG(solarpanel, 1, 17449) OVER( ORDER BY season) as kwh
      , SUM(sun_hrs) as hours
      , (solarpanel - LAG(solarpanel, 1, 17449) OVER( ORDER BY season))/(SUM(sun_hrs)) as efficiency
   FROM kv28c_meterreadings_readings 
  WHERE reading = 12 
  ORDER BY season
```

CTE - a cte to separate kwh from hours.

```
WITH power AS
     ( SELECT season
            , solarpanel - LAG(solarpanel, 1, 17449) OVER( ORDER BY season) as kwh
         FROM kv28c_meterreadings_readings 
        WHERE reading = 12 
     )
     , sun AS
     ( SELECT season
            , SUM(sun_hrs) AS hours
         FROM kv28c_meterreadings_readings    
     )
 SELECT power.season
      , power.kwh / sun.hours AS efficiency
   FROM power
   JOIN sun ON power.season = sun.season
  ORDER BY power.season
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. Sorry for the delay in getting back!

Both seems to work, but only returns values for one season, but I got a bit further!